# Rule for Cast operator validity when Interface held type is converted to a final class Type according to JLS

Tags: java, generics, casting, jls, parameterization

Consider the following clause of JLS 8 [§5.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1)

> Blockquote
> If S is an interface type:
>
> ...
>
> > If T is a class type that is final, then:
> >
> > ...
> >
> > > – Otherwise, S is either a parameterized type that is an invocation of some
> > > generic type declaration G, or a raw type corresponding to a generic type
> > > declaration G. Then there must exist a supertype X of T, such that X is an
> > > invocation of G, or a compile-time error occurs.

Here is the code example I tried to frame based on my understanding:

```java
class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    S_intrf S = new S_clss();
    T_clss T = (T_clss) S;
  }
}

interface G<T> {}

interface S_intrf extends G<String> {}
class S_clss implements S_intrf {}

interface X extends G<String> {}
final class T_clss implements X {}
```

**The diagram shows what I tried to implement in the example:**
[image]

- Here the `interface G<>` is the generic super type that is being used to generate other types based on the clause:
- **Not sure why I am getting compilation error at that section?**
- In the `S -> T` conversion - my target type is Parameterized type and final type which is complying all the rules that JLS mentions for validity of the cast operation.

Comment: Excellently asked :) Putting the effort into asking a question properly is to be commended.

Comment: There’s a logical error in your reasoning. If the specification says “if X then an error occurs”, it does not imply that “if not X then no error occurs”. Your code still has to obey the other, not cited rules. Besides that, *S* is `S_intrf` and `S_intrf` is not a parameterized type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overcomplicated matters. Let's first ditch the generics:

```java
class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    S_intrf S = new S_clss();
    T_clss T = (T_clss) S;
  }
}

interface G {}

interface S_intrf extends G {}
class S_clss implements S_intrf {}

interface X extends G {}
final class T_clss implements X {}
```

and try to compile that, which produces the exact same error. Hence the generics don't matter and just muddy the waters. They do not explain this error.

As you can see from your own diagram you made, there is an exclusionary principle at work:

- There is some unknown type; this is the *actual* type of the object that expression `S` resolves to.
- We do know a few things about this unknown type; we know it **has to be** an object (because it's a reference variable), and that object has `S_intrf` in its type hierarchy. After all, if that wasn't the case, we could never get here; the JVM does not let you assign a reference to an object that isn't to variable `S`, given that it is declared as being of type `S_intrf`. This is an absolute guarantee: You can't make `javac` compile code so that this doesn't hold, and if you try to use bytecode manipulation shenanigans, the verifier will refuse to load the class.

Given that knowledge, we can surmise one more thing: This unknown type, whatever it might be, **cannot possibly be `T_clss` or any subtype of it**. We know this because `T_clss` is final (therefore, no subtype of it can exist), *and*, it does not itself implement `S_intrf`.

Hence, the cast will necessarily fail, it can't not. And in the Java Lang Spec, there's a rule that says the compiler must reject such a situation with a compile time error.

We can 'prove' this by reading the JLS, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. A more pragmatic way to show this truly is the answer, is to simply remove the `final`. Now, it *does* compile! If you then run it, you get, as expected, a `ClassCastException`.

Without `final`, one could write e.g. `class Example extends T_clss implements S_intrf {}` and now we have a type such that an instance of this could *both* [A] be referred to by variable `S`, and [B] can be cast to `T_clss`.

By the rules of JLS, the fact that a code analyser can trivially figure out that variable `S` in fact refers to an instance of `S_clss()` is **not** taken into consideration. The rules of the analysis that leads to 'oh, the analyser says this code will always fail, therefore refuse to compile it' is set in stone, spelled out by the JLS, and a compiler must adhere to it exactly.

---

The §5.5.1 clause is most likely referring to the fact that you can use the cast operation to make assertions about the stuff in the generics part; you can for example do:

```
List<Object> foo = ...;
List<String> bar = (List<String>) foo;
```

This compiles, with a warning, as the java compiler is not going to generate any code or give you any guarantees that the list in fact only contains strings. §5.5.1 is talking about casts where the non-generics part is useless (e.g. casting an expression of type `List` to `List`, which is obviously pointless), but the generics part is relevant - e.g. the above snippet.

Comment: I understand this part that on removing generics - as you demo-ed in your example - the rules clearly breach the JLS and so compile error is caused. Even my example may not be the correct representation of what JLS wants to convey in that clause.

Comment: But what I want to understand is - that what is the hierarchy that JLS wants to demonstrate - that will follow the rule that it states above to be allowed for preventing compiler error during cast when (S : INTERFACE -> T final class) in the above setting.?

Comment: If the generics part interests you, then come up with a different example. The compiler hasn't even looked at the generics part here, whatsoever - it sees the problem with the types itself and stops looking at it.

Comment: The quote from the JLS is presumably about e.g. casting a `List<T>` (T being a typevar) to `List<String>` (String being a reified type), or casting `List` (raw type).

Comment: Based on your comments - this is what I figured out: ```class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    G<String> S = new S_clss<String>();
    T_clss<String> T = (T_clss<String>) S;
  }
}
interface G<T> {}
class S_clss<T> implements G<T> {}
final class T_clss<T> implements G<T> {}```

Comment: This seems to satisfy the clause of JLS. Please update your answer accordingly so that I can accept it :)

Comment: Edited it somewhat; I hope that clarifies matters.